# How does PhoneGap copes with new os version?

Tags: cordova

I am making my first app with PhoneGap. At the end of the summer, iOS 8 will be released.

Will the app still work on iOS 8 ?

And more generally if an app works on some os (ios, android, ...), does it keep working on the next version of the os ? PhoneGap seems to be using html5 so I guess things should work but I have better ask first before coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding as long as you are ONLY using HTML5 and no device specific features, the APP should work without any issues. 
The app will have issues if you use some device specific features and if the newer OS version has changed the API for that device specific features. Than naturally Phonegap/cordova will have to come up with an update for the specific API.
Your APP too will than need to be updated.

Comment: features like camera ?

Comment: Even PhoneGap without any plugins uses some APIs like the webview.